# org-mode task date in header - possible?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a task, that needs to be done daily with deadline in next day. So if I write in my .org file something like this:

```
** TODO Daily report
DEADLINE: <2012-07-27 Fri +1d> 
SCHEDULED: <2012-07-26 Thu +1d>
```

This produces rather nasty agenda with two lines for each day with the same text "Daily report":

```
Friday     27 July 2012
Work:       Scheduled:  TODO Daily report
Work:       Deadline:   TODO Daily report
```

What I want is to be able to see the date after "Daily report" text with date added for which day the line corresponds. For example:

```
Friday     27 July 2012
Work:       Scheduled:  TODO Daily report for 27 July 2012
Work:       Deadline:   TODO Daily report for 26 July 2012
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Hmmm. The default settings of org-mode show "In   1 d.:  TODO Daily report" for the deadline, which is nicely differentiated from the SCHEDULED line. What is the value of org-agenda-deadline-leaders on your machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

I would simply use `SCHEDULED`, not `DEADLINE`, as `SCHEDULED` implicitely means "Do it today in a single day" here, so the `DEADLINE` cookie introduces the redundancy you observe.

Answer (score 5):

You can add the following to your ~/.emacs to avoid the redundancy:

```
(setq org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-deadline-is-shown t)
```

From the documentation for this variable:

```
In the agenda of today, an entry can show up multiple times because
it is both scheduled and has a nearby deadline, and maybe a plain time
stamp as well.
When this variable is t, then only the deadline is shown and the fact that
the entry is scheduled today or was scheduled previously is not shown.
When this variable is nil, the entry will be shown several times.  When
the variable is the symbol `not-today', then skip scheduled previously,
but not scheduled today.
```

More recent version of org-mode also allow the following setting, if you prefer to keep the scheduled line instead of the deadline line:

```
(setq org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled t)
```

From the documentation:

```
This will apply on all days where a prewarning for the deadline would
be shown, but not at the day when the entry is actually due.  On that day,
the deadline will be shown anyway.
```